# How do I update a table with old value + the new value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL string which updates a row if it exists or creates a row if it does not, how do I do if it updates `ctc_portfolio_coins_amount`

If I have a value of 100, or -100, how do I either substract it or add it to the current value when it updates?

```
INSERT INTO ctc_portfolio_coins
    (ctc_portfolio_coins_portfolio_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_coin_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_amount)
    VALUES (1, 1, 100)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ctc_portfolio_coins_amount = VALUES(ctc_portfolio_coins_amount)
```

Table:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arithmetic:

```
INSERT INTO ctc_portfolio_coins (ctc_portfolio_coins_portfolio_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_coin_fk, ctc_portfolio_coins_amount)
    VALUES (1, 1, 100)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        ctc_portfolio_coins_amount = ctc_portfolio_coins_amount + VALUES(ctc_portfolio_coins_amount);
```

The reference to `ctc_portfolio_coins_amount` is the value in the column before the update.  The reference to `VALUES(ctc_portfolio_coins_amount)` is the value passed into the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Thats very nice i tried something similair just inside the `value()` thanks for the help